# Can't embed flash content in timeline profiles

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

When trying to reactive an old app we noticed that embedding flash content in posts (trying both `stream.publish` and `feed`) didn't seem to work any more. Instead, Facebook decided to throw the following error message:

> There was a problem with the parameters of the request. Body of an error/warning message. Title is: Invalid Request

Further investigation showed that they're indeed working just fine in "classic" profiles, but new timeline profiles were apparently unable to show the embedded flash content. Did anyone else experience this and/or knows a workaround?

Comment: Which API are you using?

Comment: I'm currently using the JS API

Answer (score 0):

You can publish swfs three ways.

1. Feed dialog https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/
2. API see "Graph api equivalent" on the page above
3. Share https://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/